# Linux Partition Disk usage increases as the time goes by up to 100%

Tags: kali-linux, disk-space

New to both Linux and OpenVAS.

I'm gonna try to simplify the problem outside of the specific set up.
I'm having an issue where I have my Linux (Kali) partition being filled up to 100% within a few hours. I need to find out what is causing it and see if I can fix it. Note Im also a Linux noob, some of my troubleshooting is based on what i dig up along the way.

My set up and how things started.

OpenVAS 20.08.0 on Kali causing repetitive Disk Usage FULL

1. Installed VMWare Player and created a Kali VM with 2 CPU and 4GB RAM and 30GB as Disk Space ( 10GB more than recommended)
2. Checked the disk space usage df -h (before installation) showed about 12GB used out of 20GB reserved in /dev/sda1 partition
3. Installed OpenVAS on Kali via apt-get... (It had some errors scrolling too fast during set up*)
4. Accessed the Greenbone Security Assistance (The Web Panel to run Tasks).
5. I couldnt run any simple scan because it complained about "Failed to find config..."

*In the meantime, I googled the error and coincidentally, checked my disk usage and saw my /dev/sda1 was 100% usage- so Used all 20GB reserved for this partition and didnt have any space... Odd? So naturally, i thought may be the OpenVAS feeds was huge... so I increased my VM Disk to 45GB - basically adding 15GB more to /dev/sda1. Properly gparted and increased successfully.*

6. On Next Kali boot, check available disk space...oddly enough reported back to 12GB from previously 20GB ?! PLUS my added 15GB gave me a total of 35GB now of those 12GB was used ( OpenVAS and Kali Installation). I thought may be it was temporary files used by OpenVAS or Kali which filled up the disk in the first place.
7. I also fixed some issued related to "Failed to find config..." from OpenVAS and was able to run my first scan.
8. At this point, my disk usage was still reporting about 12GB/35GB
9. I ran another local test on one single pc and left my VM on

*The next morning... I tried accessing the GSA The Panel to run a task again and it complained the service cannot run... I checked the disk usage... and again the partition was 100% at 35GB ?!*

10. I shut down the OpenVAS Service gvm-stop and shutdown the Kali VM completely... and restarted.
11. Checked back disk usage and again it dropped back to 12GB/35GB as step #6?!

So this cannot be a coincidence... something is filling up my disk space and preventing the scanning?!
Can anyone help me identify the source or suggest fixes - whether it is related to Kali rogue processes, or OpenVAS processes?

EDIT 2:
As I was looking for tools and now doing manual check on df -h, I noticed that the usage is constantly increasing by the hour... So this leads me to believe , something is filing it up.

The Only thing I added to a fresh Kali Installation was OpenVAS and ran the gvm-start. There are no ongoing Scan.

I installed ncdu to view the usage.. but Im not sure Im doing it right.
This is what I get for df -h ( The /dev/sda1 is the one increasing by the hour)

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           392M  1.5M  390M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        49G   41G  5.0G  90% /
tmpfs           2.0G   53M  1.9G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           392M   56K  391M   1% /run/user/1000
```

when i ran ncdu / ( on the root)...

```
ncdu 1.15.1 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                                 
--- / -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    8.9 GiB [##########] /usr                                                                  
.   1.5 GiB [#         ] /var
   84.4 MiB [          ] /home
   77.5 MiB [          ] /boot
.  12.6 MiB [          ] /etc
.   2.2 MiB [          ] /tmp
.   1.5 MiB [          ] /run
!  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
    8.0 KiB [          ] /media
    8.0 KiB [          ] /srv
!   4.0 KiB [          ] /root
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /opt
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /mnt
!   4.0 KiB [          ] /.cache
.   0.0   B [          ] /proc
.   0.0   B [          ] /sys
    0.0   B [          ] /dev
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
@   0.0   B [          ]  libx32
@   0.0   B [          ]  lib64
@   0.0   B [          ]  lib32
@   0.0   B [          ]  sbin
@   0.0   B [          ]  lib
@   0.0   B [          ]  bin

 Total disk usage:  10.6 GiB  Apparent size: 128.0 TiB  Items: 620787
```

I expected to see 41GB used as Total Disk usage but It is showing Total Disk Usage = 10.5GiB ?! How can I for ncdu to break down the "/" in terms of disk usage?

In other words, I wanted to find out where is the 41GB of reported usage found in the partition... Using ncdu and pointing to the mounted root, I thought it would give me the same info on disk usage as df -h  but it is reporting much less? Am i missing something?

EDIT 2: ( after I last checked, here's a new disk usgae now at 100%)
└─$ df -Th

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     392M  1.4M  390M   1% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4       49G   46G     0 100% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.0G   53M  1.9G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     392M   56K  391M   1% /run/user/1000
```

After a reboot... the disk usage seems to revert back to normal with actuaal usage to 12GB.

Somehow, it is related to the ongoing service gvm-start , which uses the disk for something and as soon as i stop gvm-stop, I can confirm it is no longer growing.

1. Is it the OpenVAS?
2. Is it the OS which is not releasing the files correctly? ( Since after reboot frees up the disk again)

EDIT 3 (SOLVED by Trial and Error on installed OpenVAS realted to the feed/sync):

Confirmed that the DISK filling up was ONLY happening when gvm-start was executed, this is the service to allow the Web Interface for GSA. Even though no scans were active, I monitored the disk usage via df -h and it was clear that this process was the cultprit...

So I checked the GVM community about similar behaviour...and stumbled upon what seems to have fixed my problem. So hopefully this will help someone else :
I ran specifically the following commands to sync the feed

```
greenbone-nvt-sync
greenbone-feed-sync --type GVMD_DATA
greenbone-feed-sync --type SCAP
greenbone-feed-sync --type CERT
```

Not sure how is this related to the constantly growing disk usage but it sounds like the service, is not longer creating files , i suspect may be logs in an infinite loop or something....

At least this solves my problem...

However, I would still like to understand the difference between disk usage reported by df -h vs ncdu ... This threw me off thinking that it was the OS corruption or some sort?!

Thanks

Comment: Check memory and swap usage with `free -h`. You don't seem to have a swap partition, but maybe there is a swap file filling up your disk. Also check files and folders usage with `du -sh <dir>`.

Comment: It appears you did not start `ncdu` as root. This will severely limit what you can see. I also suggest you use the "one file system" flag.